# Oracle's pro*C compiler and gnu C (__builtin_va_list, __attribute__, etc)

Tags: c, oracle, compilation, gnu, oracle-pro-c

I'm compiling a database library with pro*C which converts the .ppc library file to a .c file that gcc can use. However, I'm getting a lot of errors in pro*C like the following

```
   PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol
"__ attribute__ " when expecting one of
the `following`

... 

   , Encountered the symbol
"__builtin_va_list" when expecting one of
the `following`
```

The missing symbols are from a chain of standard includes like stdio.h and stdlib.h. How do I get around this issue?

The library I'm compiling came from an old solaris system that we're now upgrading (to a new solaris 10 system) and the header files don't seem to use these symbols. e.g. the newer .h files has

```
typedef __builtin_va_list va_list
```

while the old .h files has

```
typedef void* va_list
```

There are a lot of things like this so I'm reluctant to go and fix all of them manually with a typedef

Comment: Are you trying to compile in pro*C the library headers from gcc or vice versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `PARSE` param in your `$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg` to `PARTIAL` - it will use more relaxed C parsing so Pro*C don't bitch about C syntax it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it also by including this preprocessor directive. Pro*C evaluates macros and replaces them

```
#ifdef ORA_PROC
#define __attribute__(x) 
#endif
```

I'm actually at home and can't verify exactly how it is defined in our code base, I will check it and complete it but it is like the above.

Update: so the exact code we use in our project is:

```
#if defined ORA_PROC || !defined __GNUC__
#define __attribute__(x)
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
typedef          long long  int64_t;
#define INLINE
#endif
```

For an unknown reason the preprocessor is unable to have 64 bits types defined so I define them directly so that it works.
Our project is on Solaris 9 for SPARC and we compile with GCC 3.3.1 and GCC 3.4.2 and we use Oracle 10g