# while preprocessing with gnuC how to remove __extension__

Tags: c, oracle, gnu, oracle-pro-c

I need to use **Oracle pro*C** for dealing with `EXEC SQL` declaration. However I've got some macros in the SQL part that I want to replace by preprocessing with gnuC.

The problem is that from version 4, gnuC preprocessing adds keywords like `__extension__`.
The pro*C preprocessor rejects `__extension__` with the following message:

```
Syntax error at line 16, column 15, file xxx.ppc:
Error at line 16, column 15 in file xxx.ppc
__extension__ typedef unsigned long long int __u_quad_t;
..............1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "typedef" when expecting one of the followin
g:

   ; , = ( [
The symbol ";" was substituted for "typedef" to continue.
```

How to make gnuC not to produce those keywords?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem/conflict with pro*C?

Comment: pro*C rejects `__extension__` and other similar gnu keywords.

Comment: I think that the problem is related to the fact that unlike gnu C version 3, the version 4 produces those special keywords.

Projects that use preprocessing for **expanding macros** (used in SQL statements) before calling pro*C are no more working.

Hence the solution => modify all projects in order remove the need of expanding macros...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we can almost do it the other way: relaxing pro*C requirements, using the argument `parse=partial`.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468655/185460

But in this case the macro used in `VARCHAR` declarations for example are not replaced.
So the problem remains!

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to get rid of `__extension__` with the C preprocessor.  Place the following before `#include`s of headers that contain `__extension__`:

```
#define __extension__
```

This then converts `__extension__` to thin air.

But I'm not sure if it will work; I don't know the order in which things are happening with pro*C (more specifically, how pro*C and CPP work together).

Also, this may lead to other problems caused by removing it.  This simply means that you may have to do other CPP trickery to get it all working.

Comment: This is not the solution, since it would lead to add many #define.

Comment: How many, and why?  Aren't there ways around, like putting this in a common header of yours for example?

Comment: I was thinking of it, but I will not try to circumvent gnuC new behaviour. I believe that it is better to remove the need for preprocessing with gnuC prior to passing to pro*C => modify all projects :(