# Oracle Pro*C precompilation: Syntax error at line 166, column 45, file /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h PCC-S-02014

Tags: oracle, proc

I'm preparin a new Oracle Linux 8.6 machine with just an Oracle Client 19c client which should also compile some Pro*C code but when trying to compile a simple proc code, like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
printf("Stefan's Hello world!");
return(0);
}
```

I'm getting errors like:

```
$ proc iname=mytest.pc

Pro*C/C++: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Nov 16 14:32:43 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /u01/app/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Syntax error at line 166, column 45, file /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:
Error at line 166, column 45 in file /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
#define __glibc_fortify(f, __l, __s, __osz, ...) \
............................................1
PCC-S-02014, Encountered the symbol "..." when expecting one of the following:

   an identifier, define, elif, else, endif, error, if, ifdef,
   ifndef, include, include_next, line, pragma, undef, exec,
   sql, begin, end, var, type, oracle,
   an immediate preprocessor command, a C token, create,
   function, package, procedure, trigger, or, replace,

Syntax error at line 168, column 9, file /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:
Error at line 168, column 9 in file /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
   ? __ ## f ## _alias (__VA_ARGS__)                                          \
........1
PCC-S-02014, Encountered the symbol "##" when expecting one of the following:

   ; { } , = : ( ) [ ] * ? | & < > + - / % ~ ! . # @ ^ *= /= %=
   += -= <<= >>= &&= ||= ^= ~= := | & == != <= >= << >> ++ -- ->
   ... .. <> ** => an identifier, a string, a numeric constant,
   a sql string, misc. punctuation, newline, define, elif, else,
   endif, error, if, ifdef, ifndef, include, include_next, line,
   pragma, undef, exec, sql, begin, end, var, type, oracle,
   an immediate preprocessor command, a C token, exec sql,
   exec sql include, exec sql var, exec sql begin, exec sql end,
   end-exec, exec sql type, exec oracle, exec oracle else,
   exec oracle endif, exec oracle begin, a sql hint, create,
   function, package, procedure, trigger, or, replace,
   a C++ token,
```

I think is related to something incorrect in the libraries configuration but I cannot understand what.

Strange is that I prepared a fresh new VM with the same packages and is working (I documented all steps and replicated on another machine).

the content of /u01/app/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg is

```
sys_include=($ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public,/usr/include,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include)
ltype=short
define=__x86_64__
define=_MATH_H
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We're experiencing the same problem on RHEL 8.7 

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my deleted post, we have the same problem on our redhat 8 environment. We finally manage to overcome this by downgrading the glibc-headers on our environment.
We are currently opening a case at Oracle and another one at RedHat as they will automatically blame each other.
Hope this help.

Comment: Hi Matt, we followed almost the same approach.  One server had no problems with
glibc-headers-2.28-189.5.0.1.el8_6.x86_64
and a new one fails with
glibc-headers-2.28-211.0.1.el8.x86_64

We just created a new directory, placed the old, working sys/cdefs.h in it and added its path (without the sys) to the beginning of pcscfg.cfg  
This way we still have the fixes in glibc but proc precompiling doesn't fail.

Would you be so kind as letting know what Oracle gives you as a solution ?  Thx !

Comment: Oracle proc doesn't recognize ... as a Variadic Macro ( see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html )

Comment: Off course I'll let you know their answer. Also thanks to have shared your work around.

Comment: Yes. That's what I did too. Except that I cannot modify pcscfg.cfg as it is readonly and we user have not the rights to edit system files (working for a big institution is a chore sometime). I modified my command line to use a local .cfg file (command line is higher priority) with the path to the system include modified to the old version of the header files.

Answer (score 1):

gcc (and other compilers) have non-standard extensions and unique features which are unknown for Pro*C

The solution that worked for me is creating dummy header files for Pro*C. These files should have minimal to no content, just enough to make precompiling possible.

Now I created a github repo, you might want to try it: https://github.com/lzsiga/proc_include

Comment: This is a perfect solution.  Thank you for sharing !  Header files will change again and PRO*C will fail again, but with this solution, we're safe.  
A second advantage is a fixed include dir in pcscfg.cfg that does not change on new gcc versions.  Excellent !

Answer (score 0):

With oracle patch 34765931 the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to change (or add, if not present) 'parse' option to 'partial' in $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg  - it will use more relaxed C parsing so Pro*C would ignore the C syntax it doesn't understand.

This solution comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468655/2356843.

I find that the solution works for both 19.3 and 21.3 clients (or pro*C precompiler included therein).

Also, the option names seem to be case insensitive. 'parse' or 'PARSE' both work.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been plaguing me since I first upgraded from 12c to 19c and the only previous solution I could get to work was the downgrade glibc approach mention above. But I recently upgraded again and couldn't find a combination that would work. Searching I found this post and Lorinxzy's great solution. I was going to try it, but in the process I looked at my pc file again and realized I didn't need the standard C includes at all. I had built a web service application using gSoap and had put all the Oracle calls in the pc file. I had a separate C file for the other code. Removing the includes from the pc file worked, the pre-processor ran without issue. So if you are able to organize your code this way, this pre-processor issue is avoided.

Answer (score -2):

The *only* way I found around this is to update to OIC-21.8

I HATE Oracle. But then again, I hate most databases.
There is no perfect database, but some suck more than other